How to create a staking program for my own Token on Solana
I would like to launch a new SPL token on Solana.
I would like to add a new feature : a staking programm.
Basic functionality:
Stake the $TOKEN to earn more $TOKEN
I have 2 questions:
Do you know some tools or dAPP wich can do this ?
Or/And
Do you have a template a basic guidelines about how to create a staking program for a NEW SPL Token ?
Again, I don't want to stake SOL but my personal token
Thank you everyone
